# Safely inserting data in to a MySQL table and printing that

Tags: php, mysql, forum

### Safely inserting data to MySQL table and printing it afterwards.

---

Making a "sport" forum, and this part of the code is from Forum->Thread->Edit Thread.

Now I've read about Mysql real escape strings, failed to attach that to my code efficiently.

 
 
Now I'm not using prepared statements as of now.. But am going to reconstruct around them.

**Database**: uf 
**Tables**: 
forum_tbl *(Here are the "big" forums)* &

forum_post *(This is the child of forum_tbl (in a sense) and holds the Threads.)*

---

- How can I safely let an user insert data **(html content too)** to my database?

  - If there is a good way of doing this, please give a short example.
- How can I retrieve that safely set data from the database.

---

*No curly braces at the end of the code, it keeps on going... Just a part of the code.*

```
if ($_POST['editbtn']){
    if( isset($_POST['newContent']) )   
    {
        $newContent = $_POST['newContent'];
        $id      = $_POST['id'];
        $sql     = "UPDATE forum_post SET post_body='$newContent'  WHERE post_id='$id'";
        $res     = mysqli_query($mysql, $sql);  
    }
```

Comment: Off topic. Use `prepared statements` for increasing performance and security reasons.

Comment: What are `prepared statments`?

Comment: [Read out here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

Comment: Yes it will be good to use prepared statements. Else if you can use external ORM library as [link](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/) PHP Active records.

Comment: Will reconstruct around these ideas but still the question is upon us. How can I let the user post html content to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps.Pdo is a secure way of doing CRUD operations

```
    $dbhost     = "localhost";
    $dbname     = "test";
    $dbuser     = "root";
    $dbpass     = "root";
    $mysql = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);
    if( isset($_POST['newContent']) )   
    {
        $newContent = $_POST['newContent'];
        $id      = $_POST['id'];
        $sql     = "UPDATE forum_post SET post_body=? WHERE post_id=?";
        $query=$mysql->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute(array($newContent,$id));
    }
```